# MYSQL: JOIN makes SUM double

Tags: mysql, join, sum

This should be really easy. Believe me, I've been researching this for hours. My query:

```
SELECT not_piece.pid, part.name AS 'Part Name', SUM(qty_left) AS 'In Stock'
FROM not_piece 
JOIN part ON not_piece.pid = part.pid 
GROUP BY part.name;
```

Only two tables, not_piece and part.

```
select qty_left 
from not_piece 
where pid='M-MP-007r8';
```

returns 5.

Since the part.name appears twice in the parts table (that's fine), the sum is 10, not 5.

How do I make this join without doubling the sum?

Thanks.

Comment: i would GROUP BY part.name,not_piece.pid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT t.pid, p.name AS 'Part Name', t.InStock AS 'In Stock'
    FROM (SELECT pid, SUM(qty_left) AS InStock
              FROM not_piece
              GROUP BY pid) t
        INNER JOIN part p
            ON t.pid = p.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

With your GROUP BY, try grouping by your primary key, pid:

```
SELECT not_piece.pid, part.name AS 'Part Name', SUM(qty_left) AS 'In Stock'
FROM not_piece 
JOIN part ON not_piece.pid = part.pid 
GROUP BY part.pid;
```