# Mysql double join SUM invoice total and payments

Tags: mysql, sql, zend-framework

I build an invoicing system, now i try to get an view with each invoice with the total price and the amount to pay.

I left joined the invoice_part table on the invoice and summed it up, now i want to also join the payments table but when i sum it sometimes takes the payment more than once. Is there a way i can accomplish the join to only take a payment once?

```
$stmt->from(array('x'=>'invoice'),array('x.id as id','x.ref_id as ref_id','x.start_date as start_date','x.regard as regard','x.project_code as project_code'));
$stmt->joinLeft(array('ip'=>'invoice_part'),'x.id=ip.invoice_id','SUM(ip.price*ip.amount*(100-ip.discount)/100) as price_ex');
$stmt->joinLeft(array('p'=>'payment'),'x.id=p.invoice_id','SUM(ip.price*ip.amount*(100-ip.discount)*(100+tax)/10000)-IFNULL(SUM(p.amount),0) as price_open');
//joins the payment multiple times if there are multiple invoice parts, payment should only be joined once
//note: there can be multiple payments for one invoice
$stmt->group('x.id');
```

result query:

```
SELECT  `x`.`id` ,  `x`.`ref_id` ,  `x`.`start_date` ,  `x`.`regard` ,  `x`.`project_code` ,  `o`.`name` AS  `contact` ,  `d`.`name` AS  `department` ,  `c`.`name` AS  `company` ,  `is`.`name` AS  `status` , SUM( ip.price * ip.amount * ( 100 - ip.discount ) /100 ) AS  `price_ex` , SUM( ip.price * ip.amount * ( 100 - ip.discount ) * ( 100 + tax ) /10000 ) - IFNULL( SUM( p.amount ) , 0 ) AS  `price_open` 
FROM  `invoice` AS  `x` 

LEFT JOIN  `invoice_part` AS  `ip` ON x.id = ip.invoice_id
LEFT JOIN  `payment` AS  `p` ON x.id = p.invoice_id
GROUP BY  `x`.`id`
```

so when i have 2 invoice parts and 1 payment for an invoice. the payment gets counted twice. how can i only let it be counted once?

Comment: could you divide the sum by a count of invoice parts?

Answer (score 0):

You can divide the sum by the number of repetitions like this:

```
SUM(tbl.field_to_sum) / COUNT(tbl.primary_key) * COUNT(DISTINCT tbl.primary_key)
```

Also check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5682621/1541403)

Comment: Well... your sum is multiplied by the number of additional rows that come from the JOINs. You just need to divide it by that number and it will be correct. This is the most generic way to do it (that I can come up with).

Comment: yes but there can be multiple payments so this then wont work. i think i must create a subquery to do this (i hoped not to)

Comment: It should work with multiple payments too. Thats the point of SUM after all.